# Which method is better to load MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So I have a script that reads a text file, organizes it into an array then uses this code to loop through the data to input into the proper columns/rows inside MySQL server:

```
$size = sizeof($str)/14;
$x=0;

$a=0; $b=1; $c=2; $d=3; $e=4; $f=5; $g=6; $h=7; $i=8; $j=9; $k=10; $l=11; $m=12; $n=13;

mysql_query('TRUNCATE TABLE scores');


do {

$query = "INSERT INTO scores (serverid,resetid, rank,number,countryname,land,networth,tag,gov,gdi,protection,vacation,alive,deleted)
     VALUES ('$str[$a]','$str[$b]','$str[$c]','$str[$d]','$str[$e]','$str[$f]','$str[$g]','$str[$h]',
        '$str[$i]','$str[$j]','$str[$k]','$str[$l]','$str[$m]','$str[$n]')";

mysql_query($query,$conn);

$a=$a+14; $b=$b+14; $c=$c+14; $d=$d+14; $e=$e+14; $f=$f+14; $g=$g+14; $h=$h+14; $i=$i+14; $j=$j+14; $k=$k+14; $l=$l+14; $m=$m+14; $n=$n+14;
$x++;    
} while ($x != $size);


mysql_close($conn);
```

This code figures out how large the file is loops through all 13 columns until it reaches the last row in the text file.  Each time it is ran it clears the DB and loads the new data (as intended).

My question is: is this a good way of doing it?  Or is there a faster more clean way to do the same thing as my code above?

Could I use the  LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$myFile'" . " INTO TABLE ranksfeed_temp FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' to do the same job in a more efficient manner?  What are your thoughts?  I'm trying to make my code more efficient and fast.

Comment: The MySQL family of PHP is deprecated and support thereof will disappear. Please look into [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

Answer (score 2):

LOAD DATA would be faster and more efficient to import a character separated file like csv. LOAD DATA is optimized for importing large files into you MySQL table, whereas you are running one query per row from your textfile, which ist incredibly slow in execution.

Please pay attention to the fact that the `LOCAL` option is only for files which are placed on the client side of your MySQL-Server-Client Connection. Try to load the file form the machine which acts as the MySQL directly.

Disabling possible keys on your table before inserting can give you extra speed while importing. Try it with disabled keys and without to benchmark the results.

Comment: Yeah the myfile thing was just a generic thing I put in there.  In the real program I load the file from a URL.